# How can I get the line number of a SyntaxError thrown by require(id) in node.js?

Tags: node.js, try-catch, require

[image: console output]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/ummi/images/a/a1/Untitled.png))</sub>

I am trying to get access to the text I highlighted in red inside my nodejs program.  I currently have a try/catch block around the require call, but  the stack trace I dump in the catch does not contain the information I am trying to access (namely, the line number in 'testdebug.js' where the error occurred).

The lines highlighted in red are printed by something in node's internals, apparently.  How can I store that string inside of my program?  Code is below.

```
var syntaxError = true;
try {
    debugModule = require('./testdebug.js')
    syntaxError = false;
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
    //there was a syntax error.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guy knows what's up.  His module checks the code for parser errors using esprima, and gives a useful object for dissecting them.

https://github.com/substack/node-syntax-error